# PHP: error_log output of UTF8 and and unsigned values?

Tags: php

I noticed my error_log output of a UTF8 name may have entries escaped as `\xc3\xbc` instead of the actual character `ü` in UTF8 format.  Is there a way to get it to output the UTF8 sequence not escaped?

When I error_log output a variable that is a number, it always outputs negative if large, is there a way to get it to output as an unsigned integer?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file, put the following code:

```php
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')
```